# Expected value of randomly picking a random number generator

Tags: uniform-distribution, poisson-distribution

Given is a set of random numbers generators, denounced by $U_k \sim Uni[0, \frac{1}{k^2}], \: k \geq 1$.

We will randomly choose a generator by rolling a Poisson dice with some constant $\lambda$ in the next fashion: Randomly pick from $I \sim Poi(\lambda)$ and add $1$. That is the index of the generator we will use.

We will poll a random number using said random generator, and call it $X$. Find the expected value $\mathbb{E}[X]$.

I'm unsure on how to approach this, I think that choosing a random generator is $\mathbb{E}[I] + 1$ but I feel like there is a conditional expectation here.

**Update**

Going off from the comments so far: $$\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \mathbb{E}[X \mid I = k] \cdot P(I = k) $$

Seeing how $X \mid I \sim Uni(0, \frac{1}{(I+1)^2})$, we get $P(X = k) = \frac{1}{(k + 1)^2}$.

So far this leads me to
$$\begin{gather*}
    \begin{split}
        E[X] &= \sum_{k = 1}^\infty E[X \mid I = k] \cdot P(I = k) \\
        &= \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+1)^2} \cdot P(I = k) \\
        &= \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+1)^2} \cdot \frac{e^{- \lambda} \cdot \lambda^k}{k!} \\
        &= e^{-\lambda} \cdot \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(k + 1)^2} \cdot \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} \\
        &= e^{-\lambda} \cdot \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{\lambda^k}{(k + 1)(k+1)!} 
    \end{split}
\end{gather*}
$$

Is this ok? Is there a way to continue developing?

Comment: Your hunch to use conditional expectation is spot on: we have $\mathbb E[X]=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\mathbb E[X\mid I=k]\cdot\mathbb P(I=k)$. The resulting sum though is a little nasty, and its closed form needs the exponential integral. The sum would have a nicer form if $U_k$ was uniform on $[0,1/k]$.

Comment: You can now consider the exponential series and try differentiating it