# Find $E[X]$, when $X$ is a random number from Uniform$(0,1/k^2)$

Tags: probability, expected-value, random, exponential-distribution

Question:

We have a Random Number Generator defined as:

$\displaystyle U_{K} \sim \operatorname{Uni}\left[ 0,\frac{1}{k^{2}}\right] ,\ k\geqslant 1$.

We will take a random number from $I\sim \operatorname{Poi}( \lambda )$, by throwing a Poisson cube, add $1$ to the output, this will be the $k$ of our generator.

We will generate a random number with the $U_{k}$, let's call it $X$.

Find $E[ X]$.

My solution:

First, let's find what is the expected value from $I\sim \operatorname{Poi}(\lambda )$.

By definition, it is: $E[ I] =\frac{1}{\lambda}$.

Let's now add $1$ to it: $ \dfrac{1}{\lambda } +1=\dfrac{1+\lambda }{\lambda }$.

Hence, our generator is expected to look like:

$U_{\frac{1+\lambda }{\lambda }} \sim \operatorname{Uni}\left[ 0,\dfrac{1}{\left(\dfrac{1+\lambda }{\lambda }\right)^{2}}\right]$.

Since we add $1$ to the expectation $E[ I] \geqslant 0$, we are guaranteed to get a number $k\geqslant 1$.

Now, let's calculate what is the expected value from $\operatorname{Uni}\left[ 0,\dfrac{1}{\left(\dfrac{1+\lambda }{\lambda}\right)^{2}}\right]$.

This is a uniform  distribution, hence, the expectation will be:

\begin{align}
E[ X] &=\frac{\cfrac{1}{\left(\frac{1+\lambda }{\lambda }\right)^{2}}}{2}=\frac{1}{2\cdotp \left(\frac{1+\lambda }{\lambda }\right)^{2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\cfrac{2\left( 1+\lambda ^{2} +2\lambda \right)}{\lambda ^{2}}}
=\frac{\lambda ^{2}}{2+2\lambda ^{2} +4\lambda }
\end{align}

Someone sent me this solution:

$$E[ X] =\sum ^{\infty }_{0}\frac{e^{-\lambda } \lambda ^{k-1}}{( k-1) !} \cdotp \frac{1}{2k^{2}}$$

Which is completely different from mine. What did I do wrong?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3965525/expected-value-of-randomly-picking-a-random-number-generator

Comment: The point is that you can't just lump the expected value of $I$ in like you did. You need to be more careful and find the expected value of $X$ *conditional* on $I=i$, then use the formula $\mathbb E[X]=\sum\mathbb E[X\mid I=i]\cdot\mathbb P(I=i)$

Comment: Thank you, makes sense. Can I ask you what the parameters of this sum will be? I understand it should start from $k=1$, I see in the solution that it goes up to infinity, why is that?

Comment: $I$ is a Poisson variable, so can take any positive integer value. The sum is over possible values of $I$.

Comment: So why not from 0 to infinity? Why from 1?

Comment: My mistake, I meant non-negative integers. You are correct.

Answer (score 2):

The mistake in your reasoning is as follows: if $Y$ is a random variable which can be expressed in terms of another random variable $X$ in the form of an equation
$Y = f(X)$, it is not true in general that $\mathbb{E}(Y) = f(\mathbb{E}(X))$.

Comment: Got it. Thank you